# Inserting records into 1 table from 3 other tables using a 5th table to determine which records to pull

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, insert

Im using SQL-server and need to insert records into a table called "dummy" from 3 other tables based on their job number. which job numbers are being pulled is determined by the value ranges in a 5th table called "Mmay". There is not a unique key in any of the tables, and the job numbers repeat. the data from Mmay can be seen below, with jnost being the start value of the range and jnofn being the finishing value of the range.

here is the code that i tried that did not work

```
INSERT INTO dummy  (code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno)
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
     FROM accnt 
     WHERE jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn
  UNION ALL
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
     FROM jobcost 
     WHERE jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn
  UNION ALL
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
     FROM servic15 
     WHERE jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn
```

I get this error when I run the code "The multi-part identifier "Mmay.jnost" could not be bound"

[image]

so everywhere that there is a record in "accnt","jobcost", or "servic15" that has a jno in one of the ranges above, it needs to be inserted into dummy. How do I need to change my code to allow for this? Im relatively new to SQL and I think i need to use a join statement somehow, but I dont understand how to do that.

Comment: Join with Mmay in each select, e.g. FROM accnt JOIN Mmay ON jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
INSERT INTO dummy  (code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno)
SELECT
    RES.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
        FROM accnt 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
        FROM jobcost 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
        FROM servic15 
    ) RES
INNER JOIN Mmay M ON RES.jno BETWEEN M.jnost AND M.jnofn
```

Answer (score 1):

Just focus on the single queries, because this will generate the same problem:

```
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
FROM accnt 
WHERE jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn
```

Simpler problems are easier to solve.

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
FROM accnt a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Mmay
              WHERE a.jno BETWEEN Mmay.jnost AND Mmay.jnofn
             )
```

Comment: so could  I just use this same code for each select statement and put union all between each statement?

Comment: @samhatcher . .  . Yes.